# Pandas Index: identify subranges where the same value is consecutively repeated

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

### Problem Description

I'm looking for an efficient way to identify all the subranges in a `pandas` `Index` object where the same value is consecutively repeated.

### Example Problem

As a simple example, consider the following `pandas` `Index` object:

```
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.Index(['X', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'A', 'P', 'P'])
```

In this example the value `C` is repeated from location 1 through 3, the value `Q` is repeated from location 4 through 7 and the value `P` is repeated from location 9 through 10. The result that I'm then trying to get is a list of tuples (or something similar) like this:

```
[(1, 3, 'C'), (4, 7, 'Q'), (9, 10, 'P')]
```

### Tried thus far

I've been experimenting with the `pandas.Index.duplicated` property, but with this alone I haven't been able to succeed yet in getting the desired result.

### Edit:

Many thanks everyone for the great answers. I have one follow-up question. Suppose that the `Index` also contains non-contiguous duplicate values like in this example (where value `X` appears more than once):

```
idx = pd.Index(['X', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'X', 'P', 'P'])
```

How could you obtain a result that ignores the `X` values? I.e. how to get the following result for this example:

```
[(1, 3, 'C'), (4, 7, 'Q'), (9, 10, 'P')]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Original question

Where `idx = pd.Index(['X', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'A', 'P', 'P'])`.

A bit unconventional but should work, and also seems to be significantly faster:

```
# Get a new Index which is the unique duplicated values in `idx`
un = idx[idx.duplicated(keep=False)].unique()

# Call `get_loc` on `idx` for each member of `un` above  
# `np.where` gets position of True in boolean Index
res = []
for i in un:
    w = np.where(idx.get_loc(i))[0]
    # w[0], w[-1] analogous to v.min(), v.max() from @MaxU's answer
    res.append((w[0], w[-1], i))

print(res)
# [(1, 3, 'C'), (4, 7, 'Q'), (9, 10, 'P')]
```

Timing:

```
%timeit myanswer()
105 µs ± 3.19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit maxu()
1.21 ms ± 116 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Uncommented:

```
un = idx[idx.duplicated(keep=False)].unique()
res = []
for i in un:
    w = np.where(idx.get_loc(i))[0]
    res.append((w[0], w[-1], i))
```

#### Edited question

Where `idx = pd.Index(['X', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'X', 'P', 'P'])`.

To get to `un` here, first get a boolean index which is True when a value is equal the the value that comes before or after it, and False otherwise.  This is analogous to `idx.duplicated(keep=False)` in the first part.

```
b = (Series(idx).shift() == idx) | (Series(idx).shift(-1) == idx)
un = idx[b].unique()
# Rest should be the same
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way:

```
In [107]: ix = pd.Series(idx.values)

In [108]: [(v.min(), v.max(),k) for k,v in ix.groupby(ix).groups.items() if len(v) > 1]
Out[108]: [(1, 3, 'C'), (9, 10, 'P'), (4, 7, 'Q')]
```